# Set delay between loop with audio tag

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have a piece of audio autostarting and looping in the background.

ie.

```
<audio autoplay loop>
  <source src="bee_fly_by.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Is there a way I can set a delay before it plays again? So I need say a 10 second gap between the loop.

Comment: There are a few ways you should be able to do this.For more detail, check the HTML Audio/Video DOM. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) .You can call a function that  calls `pause` with a timer of 10 seconds when it has ended.There is a function to check for ended as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This really isn't very hard, you can get very fancy with this, but a simple solution with setTimeout should be pretty straightforward here.

Assuming jQuery is available on this page, something like this below should work (modify with your audio clip id if more than one on the page):

```
function wait() {
    console.log("audio clip ended, waiting 10 seconds to replay....");
    setTimeout(play, 10000);
}

function play() {
    $("audio")[0].play();
    $("audio").on("ended", wait);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Audio element has [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended_(Web_Audio)) event. but when video is looping, ended events will never fire.

So you should write code for video loop too, like this.

```
var audioControl = document.getElementById("myAudio");
audioControl.onended = function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
  var delay = setTimeout(function(){
    audioControl.play();
    clearTimeout(delay);
  }, 5000);
}
```

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5ggmdg7m/